# How to return Non-Primitive types from C# winrt component to C++?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, c++-winrt, winrt-component

I currently have a working project where I am consuming a C# WinRT component in a win32 console app using [Registration-free Winrt](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2019/04/30/enhancing-non-packaged-desktop-apps-using-windows-runtime-components/). Everything is working well, but the problem arises when I try to use Async methods from the C# component. Since `Task`s are not WinRT types, I searched around to find a solution. So what's the correct way to go about calling Async methods from a C# WinRT component?

I'm using winmdidl.exe and midlrt.exe to create my WinRT comp header file for the console app. I've also included `"Winrt/Windows.Foundation.h".

I've tried ["How to expose async methods in a Windows Runtime Component"](https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2013/03/21/how-to-expose-async-methods-in-a-windows-runtime-component/). This will build, but it errors at runtime with the daunting (imo) `Class not registered`. It's also from 2014.

C# WinRT component:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Foundation;

namespace MyComp
{
    public sealed class MyLib
    {
        public static string OtherMethods()    // only working method
        {
            return "string";
        }

            // Below methods results with `Class not registered` error
        public static IAsyncOperation<string> TestAsync()    // I think this is the problem
        {
            return TestAsyncHelper().AsAsyncOperation();
        }

        private static async Task<string> TestAsyncHelper()
        {
            // do stuff here
            return "string";
        }
        
// ******* Update ****
        public static IDictionary<int, string> GetMapOfNames()
        {
            Dictionary<int, string> retval = new Dictionary<int, string>();
            retval.Add(1, "one");
            retval.Add(2, "two");
            retval.Add(3, "three");
            retval.Add(42, "forty-two");
            retval.Add(100, "one hundred");
            return retval;
        }
    }
}
```

### Update

I noticed that this is happening with every WinRT type that isn't primitive. I'm trying to implement an `IList<int>` or `IDictionary<int, string>` and neither of those work either. I found ["Passing managed types to the Windows Runtime"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/winrt-components/creating-windows-runtime-components-in-csharp-and-visual-basic#passing-managed-types-to-the-windows-runtime) which lead to ["Returning managed types from your component"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/winrt-components/walkthrough-creating-a-simple-windows-runtime-component-and-calling-it-from-javascript#returning-managed-types-from-your-component), But every attempt I've tried has resulted in the `Class not registered` error. In the linked articles, it mentions that when passing .Net types to the WinRT component, it would appear as the corresponding WinRT type on the other side, which sounds like it should just work. I've also tried to use `IMap<int, string>`, but that errors with `IMap<K, V> is inaccessible due to its protection level`. I've updated the sample code.

Comment: Don't look at old articles, everything has changed considerably in this area since 2014. There are extensions provided for C# to transform async WinRT methods into Tasks: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windowsruntimesystemextensions.astask

Comment: I'm looking at the `AsAsyncOperation()` page and it looks about what I have in my post. IAsyncOperations are acceptable for WinRT, but I don't know what to do about the `class not registered` error since I'm using register-free WinRT.

Comment: I deleted a comment saying it worked. It does **Not** work. I made a mistake and restored an old version that ran synchronously.

Comment: Class not registered has nothing to do with async. Your question is not clear.

Comment: The original question is "how do I call an async function that is in a C# WinRT component from a C++ (unmanaged) console app". I'm trying to avoid posting an "XY problem" post. But since I haven't had any progress, I thought I would try a method. So I posted my results of that method, which is the error "Class not registered" from within the console app at runtime. Is this not the correct way of posting? Should I not try methods that I discover and post results? I'm pretty new to this, but I guess you can see that from my rep. I see your point about the error in the title, so I removed it.